# Display results in a drop-down list excluding one values in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have one drop down, in this, it's listing all the country.i  assigned two country name which is not in the array.

So I assigned to a country name in drop down
1.domestic country
2.international country

so for first one(domestic country), I assigned the value 158 which is value for India in my array.so if I choose a domestic country from dropdown it's giving me the result for India, that's correct.

The same thing I need for the international country, if I choose an international country from dropdown it should give me the result for all country expect India(158).means it should exclude India(domestic country)

```
<div class="col-sm-4 pt5">
    <select class="form-control form-control-small mb0" id="purchase_countryid" name="purchase_countryid">
        <option value="">
        <?php echo "Purchase Country"; ?></option>
        <option value="158"><?php echo "Domestic Country"; ?></option>
        <option value="-158"><?php echo "International Country"; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($myCountryList as $countrykey => $countryValue) {
            $selected = '';
            if (!empty($postArray['purchase_countryid']) && $countryValue['country_id'] == $postArray['purchase_countryid']) {
                $selected = 'selected';
            }
            echo '<option value="' . $countryValue['country_id'] . '" ' . $selected . ' title="'. $countryValue['country_name'] .'">' . $countryValue['country_name'] . '</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: need more info edit question.$myCountryList what this variable stores state or city. how are you fetching result for this. is it based on selected country or not?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy,$myCountryList are storing countery only.i am just facthing all the countery from database.the array format are below.

[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Afghanistan
            update] => 1
            offered] => N
        )
i just want if i choose internatinal countery from dropdown it should not take domeastic countery(india which have id 158)

Comment: use jquery for that. listen for onchange event for purchase_countryid then remove India from option list

Comment: Cant't we get this from php?

Comment: with your current flow no. if you use ajax to fetch list then you can do with php only